# MongoDB add new fields named with variable value

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

My question is, given few documents like this one

```
{
  deliveryDay: "2021-01-14",
  plate: {
    name: "pasta",
    quantity: 1
  }
}

{
  deliveryDay: "2021-01-16",
  plate: {
    name: "pasta",
    quantity: 3
  }
}

{
  deliveryDay: "2021-01-16",
  plate: {
    name: "pizza",
    quantity: 2
  }
}
```

There's a way to obtain the wanted result below? I tried to have a custom named field  with `$addFields` like this  `{"$deliveryDay": "$plate.quantity" }` but gives me invalid error. The aggregation is not a problem to do and I'm inside the **aggregation-framework** so I need to do it using aggregation pipeline stages.

Attended result:

```
{
  "2021-01-14": 1,
  "2021-01-16": 3,
  plate: {
    name: "pasta"
  }
}

{
  "2021-01-14": 0,
  "2021-01-16": 2,
  plate: {
    name: "pizza"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the idea is:

1. Group the documents by `deliveryDay` and `plate.name` to get the sum of `plate.quantity`.
2. Group above result again by `name` to generate an array of `[{ k: "", v: "" }]` format.
3. Concatenate `{ k: "plate", v: { name: "$_id" } }` into the above array.
4. Now convert the `array` into object using [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/).

[Solution in Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ROyogzVwHlf). Try this:

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                dDate: "$deliveryDay",
                name: "$plate.name"
            },
            sumOfQty: { $sum: "$plate.quantity" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.name",
            array: {
                $push: {
                    k: "$_id.dDate",
                    v: "$sumOfQty"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            array: {
                $concatArrays: ["$array", [{ k: "plate", v: { name: "$_id" } }]]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "2021-01-16" : 2,
    "plate" : {
        "name" : "pizza"
    }
},

/* 2 */
{
    "2021-01-14" : 1,
    "2021-01-16" : 3,
    "plate" : {
        "name" : "pasta"
    }
}
```